# Move between div elements with keyboard arrows

Tags: javascript, jquery, keyboard

I have a "search as you type" control developed by another developer who is no longer there. Basically the control at the beginning looks like below:

```
<div id="someID">
  <input type="text"/>
</div>
```

When the user searches for something. Each result is added as a new div element below the original div, like below:

```
<div id="someID">
  <input type="text"/>
</div>
<div><span>result1</span></div>
<div><span>resul2</span></div>
```

I want to add the ability to move between these divs with up and down arrows, then clicking enter to choose the div, instead of using the mouse, knowing that I don't know the exact number of divs beforehand. I read some questions on stackoverflow, but they seem to expect the exact number of divs. Any solution or guidance is appreciated.

Thanx.

Comment: Try this : https://jsfiddle.net/DinoMyte/y9x5wego/

Comment: Push each result's jQuery object into an array. Add a class to the first result which represents it's selection status, like a border. Then, detect keypresses. If it's down arrow, remove the class from current index, increase array index, and add class to jquery object at current index. Similar for up arrow.

Comment: Your question is quite broad, so I'll answer in similarly broad terms.

document.onkeydown and document.onkeyup will provide events that you can use.  In your event handler, check which key was pressed, and act accordingly (see http://www.javascripter.net/faq/onkeydown.htm)

The number of elements you have is immaterial.  You can use document.getElementsByTagName (or if you're using jQuery, one of their selectors) to select the divs in your DOM, and attach metadata and/or classes to them that indicates whether they are selected/unselected.

Comment: @Witchfinder Thanks everyone, but how can I detect that the down arrow key only be handled if I click it inside the textbox in that div? How do I handle that when the user click enter while the selection is on a specific div? How do to these things? I am kind of lost at it

Comment: @DinoMyte Thanks for ur answer, but ur example has a defined 2 elements. in my case it's dynamic, and I also want to click "enter" on a specific item.

Comment: @BrittanyR you can just change the element from document.onkeydown to element.onkeydown - DinoMyte's example shows that.  Keydown also applies to the enter key.  Write a little test script that will update a div with information about which keys you're pressing.  The number of elements on the page doesn't matter.  As long as you select the right number of elements, you can test if it's the last or first before moving the highlight context.

Comment: Thanks @Witchfinder DinoMyte's example doesn't work as expected, you can try it out, once you do a down arrow,it starts with the last element, and it never highlights the first element. Also how do I bind the enter key to click the highlighted element as if I I really clicked on it? Thanks

Comment: @BrittanyR - look at the revised example here: https://jsfiddle.net/y9x5wego/4/ - I'm sure you can work it out from there

Comment: Please add it as answer. That's exactly what I need.